# How does locale works in Linux?

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to understand how locale works in Linux. This is how I think it works:

Each process have an environment variables table, you can launch a process and set some environment variables for this process with some locale variables (for example: `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`).

But if this newly launched process wants to see what its locale variables are, it doesn't look in the environment variables table, but rather there is a separate locale variables table that the process looks at, something like this:

[image]

So if the process wants to use the locale variables that are set in its environment variables table, it should copy them into its locale variables table first. For example, to copy the `LC_ALL` variable from the environment variables table into the locale variables table, the process does the following:

```
setlocale (LC_ALL, "");
```

Am I correct in my understanding? And if I am correct, are all processes have a locale variables table, or is this table only present in programs written in C?

Comment: Are you aware of https://unix.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: They may have a local table, or they may not. Depends on the program. Nothing is stopping a program from ignoring locale, or from using the environment variables directly. Even in C, it's nowhere written in stone that a program *must* call `setlocale()`; many programs carry on happily without bothering.

Comment: You want to see this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87745/what-does-lc-all-c-do